# Repeat Error on Slick Carousel

Tags: css, css-transforms, slick.js

I'm trying to use CSS transforms to make the center object in a carousel have more focus/attention. (Carousel is Slick.js)

Everything works great, except when I go from the last item back to the first item, there is a pause and a jump before the change appears.

What is causing this? How do I fix it?

https://jsfiddle.net/6d91cqoq/1/

```
//pseudo code
```

EDIT: It also happens going from the first to the last.

EDIT 2:
It's worth noting I took the idea from the Slick.js website: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

On the page with the 'Center Mode' example, it is using transforms to do this exact thing. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is different, other than the target element.

EDIT 3: I did attempt to change my elements to `H3` elements, as is in the sample. No change.

Answer (score 0):

The cause for this is that Slick changes the DOM order of the slide elements when switching from "first to last". The transition doesn't kick in when dom elements are removed and added back... You can work around this by playing around with javascript and Slicks `beforeChange` and `afterChange` events instead of a pure CSS solution. I have made an example, although the example I made also slightly changes the effect (the center slide won't widen until it is in the center, e.g. afterChange). Maybe with Slicks, next and previous slide parameters you can make it work like your example, didn't have time to investigate it more.

https://jsfiddle.net/6d91cqoq/2/

Changes made to your example:

```
//Added my own "active" class, so it does not to interfere with slicks active class
.slick-slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.50);
}
```

JS

```
//make current center active after initialization
$('.slick-center').addClass('active');

//before slide change, make all "inactive"
$('.center').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, index){
  $('.slick-slide').removeClass('active');
});

//after change make the center one "active"
$('.center').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, index){
  $(slick.$slides[index]).addClass('active');
});
```